# How to understand Javascript syntax with colon

Tags: javascript, syntax, flowtype

I am learning Javascript and React. While I read this tutorial: https://suspicious.website/2016/04/29/starting-out-with-react-redux-starter-kit/
there are several syntax that confused me, for example:

```
export function recieveZen (value: string): Action {  
  ...
}
```

What are those colons ':' means?

Also the hard part is that: I don't know how to name those syntax to google search for an declaration... so any suggestions dealing with confused javascript syntax for newbie?

Comment: Take a look https://flowtype.org

Comment: The colon syntax is type annotations, and basically just says *"`receiveZen` is a function that takes a paramater `value` that is a `string`, and returns an `Action` object."*. It's not part of JavaScript itself, but a type checker for JavaScript called [Flow](https://flowtype.org) (which, like React, is made by Facebook).

Comment: That is exactly what I am finding. Thanks :)